# Send events from main view to view with a custom filter

Tags: google-analytics

I have two views in my GA account, main view, that collects all of data, and second view with custom filter that collect information only from site.com/example/ directory. But i need to collect events to both of them, how do i send only events to my view with /example/ filter, that exlude all other data from other directories. And all events in this path also shoud goto both of views, main view and view with filter.
Maybe someone already ask this simmilar question, but i can't found it with search.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this on topic by solving it via code you should be able to override the page path for the event, so it is not excluded by your filter. Example in analytics.js:

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',
  'eventCategory': 'Category',
  'eventAction': 'Action',
  'eventLabel': 'Label',
  'page':'/a/virtual/path/'
});
```

You could of course try to do the same via the filter (advanced filter to rename the page path where the event category matches your desired value) as long as you do it before the exclude filter.

Of course this will mess up the "pages" report in the event reports.